# Python how to avoid data type from date to nanosecond change after numpy where clause

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, etl

i have a dataset with date, what i want to do is to replace any date value that is earlier than 2000 to 2000-12-31 12:00:00, while remain the others as what it is. However, my code results convert the date value to nanosecond in false statement

My code :

```
   data['date'] = np.where(data['date']<=datetime(2000,12,31,12,0,0) , pd.to_datetime('2000-12-31 00:00:00') , data['date'])
```

My `data` table:

```
   Date                        value
   1990-01-01 12:00:00           1
   2020-12-31 12:00:00           2
```

Expected table

```
   Date                        value
   2000-12-31 12:00:00           1
   2020-12-31 12-00:00           2
```

Actual table result now

```
   Date                        Value  
   2000-12-31 12:00:00           1
   1609416000000                 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `.loc[]` function in pandas to only modify the rows that you are interested in as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

# Creating your sample dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame({'date': [pd.to_datetime('1990-01-01 12:00:00'), pd.to_datetime('2020-12-31 12:00:00')], 'Value': [1,2]})

# filtering your rows to only take the ones before 2000-12-31 12:00:00 and replacing them with 2000-12-31 00:00:00
data.loc[data['date']<=datetime(2000,12,31,12,0,0), 'date'] = pd.to_datetime('2000-12-31 00:00:00')

data.head()
```

Returns:

```
 date                   Value
 2000-12-31 00:00:00    1
 2020-12-31 12:00:00    2
```